# bootstrap：Why doesn't my col-sm-offset-3 work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use col-sm-offset-3 to indent the input field so that my input field can be centered but it doesn't work. Why? I don't understand.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylQbp.png)/Dyfbd.png

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Please include what you have tried and the result of that, AND your desired output, as well as any relevant code, and ideally a snippet also. Otherwise you will find people asking many additional questions, such as are you using a small screen? Because it will only be offset from a small screen upwards, so on an extra small screen this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of bootstrap are you using?

If `v4` than use `offset-sm-3` class instead.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.